# why does mem_fn() complain about attempt to use a deleted function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following snippet :

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(int num):num_(num){}
    void print_add(int i) const { std::cout << num_+i << '\n'; }
    int num_;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Foo*> vpf{ new Foo(3), new Foo(4), new Foo(5) };

    auto pfa =  std::mem_fn(&Foo::print_add);
    int i = 42;

    //std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), [&i](const auto& val){val -> print_add(i);});
    std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), pfa(&i));

    return 0;
}
```

Commented code that uses a lambda expression actually works as I expect printing 45, 46, 47. The uncommented code with `std::for_each` that uses `mem_fn` causes a compilation error `attempt to use a deleted function`.

Can someone explain why and how I can properly use `mem_fn` in this scenario?

Comment: Um... There's no "deleted function" error in this code. The code you provided fails to compile at `pfa(&i)`, which makes no sense. It is an attempt to call `pfa` with `int *` argument. But `pfa` is a functional object with `(Foo *, int)` arguments.

Comment: You should read what `mem_fn` actually does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) creates a functor that takes a reference or pointer to the type as the first parameter, and forwards the rest of its parameters to the actual function.

When passing it to an algorithm, you're not supposed to call it's `()` operator (you didn't do this for your lambda example). Your problem is that you also want to provide an argument to your function, and this simply isn't possible with just `mem_fn`. You can do this with [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) or a lambda, though.

```
std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), std::bind(pfa, std::placeholders::_1, i));
```

or

```
std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), [&i,&pfa](const auto& val){ pfa(val, i); });
```

That being said, I think it's best to go with the lambda from your example. `bind` is controvesial, and if you're using a lambda anyway, what's the point of adding `mem_fn` to it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you could possibly obtain a "attempt to use a deleted function" error from this code. Either the code is inaccurate, or that diagnostic message is not the first one in the list.

The very first error in this code would refer to your `pfa(&i)` subexpression, which is invalid. Firstly, in order to *call* `pfa` you'd have to supply two arguments - of `Foo *` and `int` type - while you are supplying just one of `int *` type. Secondly, in the context of `std::for_each` you are not supposed to *call* `pfa` yourself at all, you are supposed to *pass* `pfa` itself to `std::for_each`.

If you wanted to replace your lambda with something "lambdaless", e.g. using the  "classic" `std::mem_fn` functional object, it would look as follows

```
auto pfa = std::mem_fn(&Foo::print_add);
int i = 42;
std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), std::bind(pfa, std::placeholders::_1, i));
```

or, using the now-deprecated C++98 library features

```
auto pfa = std::mem_fun(&Foo::print_add);
int i = 42;
std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), std::bind2nd(pfa, i));
```

(Back then it was just... more fun somehow. More *fun*. Geddit? Ha ha ha... )

**P.S.** Note that (as @T.C. noted in the comments), there's no need to pre-wrap a member pointer through `std::mem_fn`, if you are planning to use `std::bind` on it. The first variant can be rewritten as

```
int i = 42;
std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), 
  std::bind(&Foo::print_add, std::placeholders::_1, i));
```

Comment: There's no need for `mem_fn` if you are using `bind`.

Comment: @T.C.: True. I kinda focused on fixing the OP's `for_each` line, trying to keep the rest unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

```
auto pfa =  std::mem_fn(&Foo::print_add);
```

`&Foo::print_add` is not a function pointer. It is a class method pointer. You can't invoke it as a function pointer. You have to come up with an instance of the class for this method, and invoke the instance's method via the pointer.

```
std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(), pfa(&i));
```

You are trying to invoke `pfa` as if it was a function pointer it is not. First of all, `std::for_each` passes the item in the sequence it iterates over, for each invocation. That's going to be the class instance you need to use with the method pointer:

```
std::for_each(vpf.begin(), vpf.end(),
          [&i,&pfa](const auto& val){pfa(val, i);});
```

The lambda takes its parameter, the value in the sequence `std::for_each` iterates over, and uses it to invoke the class method, via the method pointer. As expected, the resulting output from this is

```
45
46
47
```

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted. This is a valid answer.

Comment: It is, I verified the expected results. Somebody is having a bad hair day.

Comment: No reason to downvote, but it appears that the OP's intent is to use `std::mem_fn` to reimplement the original lambda (see the commented-out code)  without any lambdas at all. Meaning that wrapping his `pfa` into a lambda would defeat the purpose of introducing `pfa` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, all the answers are correct. I just upvoted your answer as I don't know why it got downvoted either. I'll accept @krzaq's answer as I was indeed trying to use `std::mem_fn` in lieu of lambda and `std::bind` seems to be the only way to do it for member functions w/ parameters.